# Animating in jquery: running a function after a group of animation finishes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm animating a group of divs that need to move together. Each div will follow a different path, and will move at same time, for the same period.

After this piece of the animation is over, I'd like to run some code to redraw some other stuff.

I'm using jquery for this. Here is a sample code of what I'm doing:

```
    // units is an array containing the divs encapsulated on $()
for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++)
{
    var unit = units[i];
    var idUnit = unit.attr('id');

            // New coordinates
    var xNew = layout.x[idUnit];
    var yNew = layout.y[idUnit];

            // Actual coordinates
    var xAct = x(unit);
    var yAct = y(unit);

            // Animate!
    unit.animate(
            {left: xNew, top: yNew}, {
                duration: 1000, 
                easing: 'easeOutBack'
            }
    );
}
```

I could put the code I want to execute on the complete callback of one of the animate calls, but I'm looking for something like this:

```
queue.delay(1000).run(function(opts) {

   // Code goes here!

});
```

Is there a way to do this? Or should I rewrite my code to work with only one call to animate, and pass to it a custom stepper function?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a jQuery variable named `$units` that holds all the elements to be animated, you can do this:

```
$units.each(function() {
    var $unit = $(this),
        id = $unit.attr('id');

    var xNew = layout.x[id],
        yNew = layout.y[id];

    $unit.animate({ left: xNew, top: yNew },
        { duration: 1000,  easing: 'easeOutBack' });
}).promise().done(function() {
    // This will execute after all the animations have finished.
});
```

Comment: Works nicely! I took me some time to understand promise. I really need to take some time to study jquery more deeply!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(function () { /* do callback */ }, 1000)` where 1000 is your duration of pause. Add this line just after the for loop.

Comment: I thought doing that, but I have some concerns with synchronization. If I use the jquery animation API, jquery will put everything that should start at the same time in the same call, right? If I have some other animation scheduled to start at the same time of this call to setTimeout, my code would have a race condition, and I wouldn't known which call would be executed first, right?